# Hi , while using passport.js for OAuth I am getting middleware not used even though I am not using sessions

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am new to node.js and am currently working on my first project.
While using passport.js for OAuth it is giving me

```
Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (C:\Users\Rohit\Documents\Projects\server\node_modules\passport\lib\http\re
quest.js:46:34)
```

error even though I am not using sessions at the moment . But when I comment out my 'done()' function it stops showing this error. As per my knowledge I have to use 'passport.initialize()' only when I make use of sessions. Can someone please help me out!

index.js :-

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('./config/keys');
require('./models/User');
require('./services/passport');

const app = express();

mongoose.connect
(
  keys.mongoURI,
  {
    useNewUrlParser : true,
    useCreateIndex : true,
    useUnifiedTopology : true,
  }
)
.then(() => console.log('Mongoose connected ...'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

require('./routes/authroutes')(app);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

passport.js:-

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy
  (
    {
      clientID : keys.googleClientID,
      clientSecret : keys.googleClientSecret,
      callbackURL : '/auth/google/callback'
    },
    (acessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) =>
    {
        //console.log(profile);
        User.findOne({ googleID : profile.id})
          .then(
            (existingUser) =>
            {
              if(existingUser)
              {
                //there is already a user with this emailin our adatbase
                console.log('User already exists!');
                done(null, existingUser);
              }
              else
              {
                //NEW User
                console.log('New User!\n');
                new User({ googleID : profile.id})
                .save()
                .then
                  (
                     user => done(null, user)
                  );
              }
            }
        );
    }
  )
);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In a Connect or Express-based application, passport.initialize()
> middleware is required to initialize Passport. If your application
> uses persistent login sessions, passport.session() middleware must
> also be used.

http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/

`passport.initialize()` is a middleware that you should use which initialize Passport. This is the error that you have.

Add `passport.initialize()` before declaring routes.

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport'); // Calling passport
const keys = require('./config/keys');
require('./models/User');
require('./services/passport'); // Calling the passport setup you've defined in passport.js

const app = express();
app.use(passport.initialize());

mongoose.connect
(
  keys.mongoURI,
  {
    useNewUrlParser : true,
    useCreateIndex : true,
    useUnifiedTopology : true,
  }
)
.then(() => console.log('Mongoose connected ...'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

require('./routes/authroutes')(app);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

Refer: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/downloads/html/

If you are using sessions, you need to specify as shown below in your index.js file.

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Also, add `serializeUser` & `deserializeUser` to the passport-setup (Your `passport.js` file)

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy
  (
    {
      clientID : keys.googleClientID,
      clientSecret : keys.googleClientSecret,
      callbackURL : '/auth/google/callback'
    },
    (acessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) =>
    {
        //console.log(profile);
        User.findOne({ googleID : profile.id})
          .then(
            (existingUser) =>
            {
              if(existingUser)
              {
                //there is already a user with this emailin our adatbase
                console.log('User already exists!');
                done(null, existingUser);
              }
              else
              {
                //NEW User
                console.log('New User!\n');
                new User({ googleID : profile.id})
                .save()
                .then
                  (
                     user => done(null, user)
                  );
              }
            }
        );
    }
  )
);
```

As per naming conventions, I would suggest you to rename `passport.js` to `passport-setup.js` because this may cause confusion. Also, this is a good practice.

I hope this answer helps you.

Thanks.